# Make one true while others in object to false in react hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

**What is the best to make (option 1: true ) and at the same time need to change others state to false**

> the same thing needs to do with other states too ,
> (option2,option3.....)

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
        option1: false,
        option2: false,
        option3: false,
        option4: false,
    });

return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => setState(state => ({ ...state, option1: true }))}
        />

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => setState(state => ({ ...state, option2: true }))}
        />

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => setState(state => ({ ...state, option3: true }))}
        />
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use a helper function and bind it to the checkboxes' `click` event. You can pass the target `option` as a param to the function. The function will run a loop and set false to all the `option` except the target `option` will be set to true.

Comment: You could try doing `useState({ selectedOption: 0 });` along with `onClick={() => setState(state => ({ selectedOption: 1 }))}` etc etc. And if you need the 4 booleans somewhere else, then you can derive those from this single state value.

Comment: On another note: don't forget that a further click on the same checkbox will toggle it OFF again, yet so far you run the same code regardless of whether it was toggled ON or OFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your state only consist `options` variables then

```
const initialState = {
        option1: false,
        option2: false,
        option3: false,
        option4: false,
    }
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

return (
    <div>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => setState(state => ({ ...initialState, option1: true }))}
        />

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => setState(state => ({ ...initialState, option2: true }))}
        />

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => setState(state => ({ ...initialState, option3: true }))}
        />
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was writing the exact thing as Prakash's answer... Seems to be the simplest way...

although I like to write my constants with caps so `INITIAL_STATE` rather than `initialState`  #personalPreferences

Comment: This isn't an answer in itself and would be better suited as a comment under the mentioned answer, or as a comment under the question.

Comment: True, thanks Peter B for the tip. Still new to this :)  Waiting for my 50 rep so I can comment properly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you wouldn't want to use a radio button to do this but heres some code which works for your usecase.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const initialState = {
  option1: false,
  option2: false,
  option3: false,
  option4: false
};

export default function Hello({ name }) {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initialState);

  function updateForm(option) {
    const newState = { ...initialState }; // create new state object from initialState, spread the initialState to keep it immutable
    newState[option] = true; // set the selected option to true
    setFormState(newState); // update state with new state
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={() => updateForm("option1")}
        checked={formState.option1}
      />

      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={() => updateForm("option2")}
        checked={formState.option2}
      />

      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={() => updateForm("option3")}
        checked={formState.option3}
      />

      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={() => updateForm("option4")}
        checked={formState.option4}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```